# Predict Soccer Match with empty variables in test set

Tags: predictive-models, caret

I have a dataset with soccer results and a lot of meta data like corners, result in the half time, fouls etc.
To traing the algorithm (in my case Support Vector Machine) is use all this variables.

```
library(caret)
train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)
svmModel <- train(HomeGoals~HomeTeam+AwayTeam+AwayGoals+FTR+HTHG+HTR+HS+AS+HST+AST+HF+AF+HC+AC+HY+AY+HR+AR,data[1:1500,], method="svmLinear",trControl=train_control)
```

Now I want to predict the final result of a game in the future. Of course I do not have the statistics like corners, fouls etc. yet. I just have the team names. Is there a way to pass "empty" variables to the algorithm, because the dataframe to predict must contain all columns as in the test set.
Or does it only makes sense to train the algorithm just with the team names and the final result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the methodology. You trained your algorithm on aggregated data from the whole match. That is, your algorithm learned how to predict the end result of a match given all the statistics of the match, or in other words, *a posteriori*. It wasn't trained to predict the end result of a match before that match actually happened.

So, no, you can't pass an empty data.frame to it, that wouldn't make sense.

What makes sense is to train an algorithm on data know *a priori* to predict the end result (you'll probably come to the realization there's not much predictive power in that), or alternatively trying to predict results given past events, like a time series. This problem can also be coerced to a survival analysis.